# Is there a way to automatically schedule the bootup of a Lightsail instance every 3 months?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, aws-cli, certbot, amazon-lightsail

I'm looking to automatically renew my SSL certificates for a website I'm hosting on GitLab pages using certbot auto. I already have this working, but I have to keep my Lightsail instance running continuously.

I'm just looking for an automatic way to boot up my Lightsail instance every 3 months, and once booted run a little script, and then power down again. At the moment it's costing me $5 month, and I'm only using it for a few minutes each time.

Is there a way to automatically schedule the bootup of a Lightsail instance every 3 months?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suggested approach: A scheduled Lambda function that fires every 3 months and performs 4 steps.

1. Start up your instance
2. Use the EC2 RunCommand API to remotely execute a command on your lightsail instance
3. Monitor the command until complete
4. Shut down the instance

Some prerequisites:

- Create a Lambda function and grant it permissions with an IAM role to use `ssm:*`, `ec2:startinstances` and `ec2:stopinstances` (This will allow your lambda function to communicate to your lightsail instance and also  monitor and send commands.
- Make the lambda function a scheduled function, so you can trigger it every 3 months automaticalle
- Have SSMAgent installed on your instance like [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/ssm-agent.html)
- Give your instance the appropriate IAM permissions for SSM communications through an instance policy (This will allow the instance to communicate with AWS SSM)

  `"ec2messages:*","ssm:updateinstanceinformation","ssm:listassociations"`

Now write your lambda function using the AWS SDK and it'll work like a charm.
If you're worried about costs, unless you run one mother of a script, you should fall within the free tier as you get 400 GB-seconds of compute time per month.

This means you can run a lambda function with 1GB of memory for 400 seconds every month for free.

PS: I mentioned EC2 alot, I'm aware you're using lightsail but as it's just a wrapper for EC2 I imagine the same functionality is available, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Thanks so much, and a nice amount of detail to help me figure this out.

Comment: If it takes longer than 5 minutes for the Lightsail instance to start and perform whatever operation it needs to, then this will be really difficult to pull off with your suggested approach. The better approach would be as helloV suggested, to have the Lambda function simply start the instance, then have the instance run the task automatically on boot, and shut itself down once the task is complete.

Comment: I also agree with @helloV here that using AWS DataPipeline would be a smoother experience to set up. It would force you from lightsail to ec2 but since the cost for running it for just an hour is next to nothing ($0.0116/hour in us-east-1) it's an equally viable option.

Answer (score 4):

There are two options I can think of. There may be more.

[AWS Data Pipeline](https://aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/): Schedule a shell activity every 3 months and choose a micro instance. Specify the AWS CLI commands to start your instance and have your instance send stop instance command once it is done with its work. **Cost: 1 hour of micro instance.**

[AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/)(Preferred): Schedule a Lambda event to start your instance every 3 months. Specify the AWS CLI commands to start your instance and have your instance send stop instance command once it is done with its work. **Cost: Nothing** (likely to be within free limits)

[aws lightsail start-instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lightsail/start-instance.html)

> Starts a specific Amazon Lightsail instance from a stopped state. To
>   restart an instance, use the reboot instance operation.

In my opinion, installing an agent on your instance is an overkill just to send a command.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, very helpful.

Comment: @helloV JFYI - the SSM agent is pre-packaged with most of AWS's AMI's. It is very likely OP's lightsail instance will use AWS Linux as their AMI.

Answer (score 1):

To do so, we will need to take help from different AWS Services, we will need to make a Lambda function and write a custom code for starting and stopping the LightSail Instance and then use CloudWatch Events to schedule the Instance for the time period you want.

Below is a sample code you can use to schedule the stop and start of the Instance:

## Code to Start the LightSail server:

```
import json
import boto3
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.client('lightsail', region_name='REGION')
    response = client.start_instance(
    instanceName='NAME-OF-YOUR-LIGHTSAIL-SERVER'
)
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

## Code to Stop the LightSail server:

```
import json
import boto3
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.client('lightsail', region_name='REGION')
    response = client.stop_instance(
    instanceName='NAME-OF-YOUR-LIGHTSAIL-SERVER'
)
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

NOTE**: Make sure to edit REGION and NAME-OF-YOUR-LIGHTSAIL-SERVER

You can create two different lambda functions, using above code.

Once you do so, you can use CloudWatch Events Rule that triggers the Lambda function.

Please refer: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/Create-CloudWatch-Events-Rule.html

Comment: should i create  separate jobs ?

Comment: and how to add these jobs